# How do I download data from my google compute engine windows server VM OR upload data from that VM to a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a google compute VM instance running Windows Server 2019 that that has data in a folder that I want transferred to my local desktop (around 10GB, 200000 files).

I have no idea how to do it properly and efficiently. If I try from the browser in the VM, to a bucket or even google drive, the browser crashes before its complete. Online resources offer the "SSH" option in the VM console, but thats only for non-windows instances. I couldn't find a way to use the google cloud sdk shell, there were only options to upload from a local desktop to a bucket.

So how can I efficiently get my data off my google windows VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use two different methods. The following methods require setup.

1) Use `gsutil` to copy the files from Windows to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). Then download the files to my desktop. I often use this method as the upload to GCS is very fast. The download from GCS to my desktop performance depends on my Internet connection speed.

2) Install an SSH server on Windows. I use both the built-in Windows OpenSSH server and the BitVise SSH server. This allows me to use GUI SSH clients to transfer files directly from Windows to my desktop. Both SSH servers work well but I prefer BitVise because I use their SSH client constantly. This method also supports Rsync over SSH which optimizes file transfers.

An additional method is drive mapping over RDP. This method is OK for small transfers but I have frequent failures for large transfers even over reliable Gigabit Internet connections.

[OpenSSH for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

[Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server)

[How to Transfer Files with Rsync over SSH](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-transfer-files-with-rsync-over-ssh/)